# Parse JSON with dynamic property name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

JSON structure

```
{
  "error": "RecordInvalid",
  "description": "Record validation errors",
  "details": {
  "email": [
   {
     "description": "Email: mark.vaugh@gmail.com is already being used by another user",
     "error": "DuplicateValue"
   }
 ],
 "name": [
  {
    "description": "Name: is too short (minimum one character)",
    "error": "ValueTooShort"
  }
 ]
 }
 }
```

Property names "details", "details:email", and "details:name" are dynamic(see screenshot)
[image]

Here are the POCO classes:

```
public class ZendeskError
{
    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<ErrorKeyValue>> ErrorDetails { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
public class ErrorKeyValue
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, List<PropertyFailureInformation>> PropertyError { get; set; }

}

public class PropertyFailureInformation
{
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works well except the binding to class PropertyFailureInformation - see screenshot.
[image]

Please advise where I am going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize a JSON object with dynamic property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588347/how-can-i-deserialize-a-json-object-with-dynamic-property-names)

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `public Dictionary<string, List<PropertyFailureInformation>> ErrorDetails { get; set; }`? I don't see why you need the extra `KeyValuePair<string, List<PropertyFailureInformation>>`, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @canton7 You are absolutely right - Thanks! That worked and silly me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `ErrorKeyValue`. `ErrorDetails` should just be:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<PropertyFailureInformation>> ErrorDetails { get; set; }
```

That is:

```
public class ZendeskError
{
    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<PropertyFailureInformation>> ErrorDetails { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyFailureInformation
{
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

[See DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x7tXQ2)